# atom: atom-runner cant find images / use them with pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame, atom-editor

using python 36, 
pygame 1.9.3, 
atom 1.13 text editor

First time asking a question here on stack overflow.

For some reason when loading up an image (in the same folder as the .py file) like so:

```
background_image = pygame.image.load('my background.png').convert()
```

set my blit line, and running it with atom runner I get this error:

```
pygame.error: Couldn't open my background.png
```

but when I double click on the actual .py file, my image loads fine.

also, if I actually type the full directory path of the image in atom, the image loads fine.

I'm pretty new to coding. I'm guessing this has something to do with "path"? I've only messed with paths to make atom runner use the proper pygame version, but I have no idea why it won't load my image file like the python IDLE does.

Comment: You're using a file with a space in the name, so it's possible that the interpreter is getting confused, and thinking that `my` is the file to open, and `background.png` is another command. Have you tried with a file without a space in the name?

Comment: just tried mybackground.png no spaces, and it threw me the same error... so strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that atom-runner uses the Atom project path as the working directory when running a program.  Your program is assuming the working directory is same as the folder the image is in.  You need to either set up an Atom project with that as the root folder, or use 'os.path' to set the proper path to the image, like so:

```
from os import path

working_dir = path.dirname(__file__)
background_image = pygame.image.load(path.join(working_dir, 'my background.png')).convert()
```

Comment: Gotcha, and thank you. Those lines worked. Didn't know that about the atom-runner.